# How to find the probability mass function of the following random variables.

Tags: probability

How to find the probability mass function of the following random variables.

Let $X$ be a random variable with probability mass function

$$P(X=r) = (_nC_r)p^r(1-p)^{n-r}$$

Then what will be the probability mass function of $aX+b$ and $X^2$

To find the probability mass function of $aX+b$ we know that, assuming $a \ne 0$, then we see that

$$ P(Y = y) = P\left(X= \frac{y-b}{a}\right) $$

I am not sure how to proceed from here.

$P(Y = y) = P\left(X= \sqrt{y}\right)$ where $y>0$.

I am also confused how to proceed from here

Comment: Does this help? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/507677/linear-transformation-of-a-binomial-random-variable

Comment: Let $p_r=\mathbb P(X=r)$, and consider the sequence $\{p_r : r\in \mathbb N_0\}$, where $\mathbb  N_0$ denotes the set of nonnegative integers. The random variables $aX+b$ and $X^2$ have probability mass functions with this same sequence of probabilities, but on the sequences $\{ar + b : r\in\mathbb N_0\}$ and  $\{r^2 : r\in\mathbb N_0\}$, respectively.